# Error "Error populating database: Could not execute query: BLOB/TEXT column 'ignoremeta' can't have a default value"

Tags: server

I'm trying to install centovacast on my server but during installation i got this error "Error populating database: Could not execute query: BLOB/TEXT column 'ignoremeta' can't have a default value" anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?